# How to add a new features to an existing shapefile using Geotools?

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I have a shapefile with some points. I would like to add a new points to this shapefile using Geotools.

Comment: The best way to learn how to do this is to go through their tutorials.  They have a tutorial (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html) that will introduce you to the concepts needed to add features to existing shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapefiles are essentially write once (in GeoTools) so read in the file and then write the features including the new ones out to a new shapefile.